# ng controller hello world diff between 1.3 to 1.4.7

Tags: angularjs

I am following along a tutorial for angualr js that is in angular 1.3 ,but I am using the lastest stable version 1.4.7. The following code doesnt work in 1.4.7 although it does in 1.3.2. Could you please tell me the changes I need to do for the code to work ?

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>


JavaScript :

var MainController = function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
};
```

I am using the online tool plunker to code.

Can you please tell me the changes I need to make ?

Comment: Are you using a global ngController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global controller constructors are disabled by default since version **1.3.0-beta.15**.

In later versions use this instead:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
});
```

And:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XWv50NKr5ojiplbMHI59?p=preview